# multiple rows into single row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to flatten(I am not sure whether is the correct thing to call it flatten) the columns with rows. multiple rows into single row with column change to column_rows
I have a dataframe as below:

```
data = {"a":[3,4,5,6],
      "b":[88,77,66,55],
      "c":["ts", "new", "thing", "here"],
      "d":[9.1,9.2,9.0,8.4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

my current output is:

```
    a   b   c   d
0   3   88  ts  9.1
1   4   77  new 9.2
2   5   66  thing   9.0
3   6   55  here    8.4
```

my expected otput:

```
    a_0  a_1 a_2 a_3 b_0 b_1 b_2 b_3 c_0 c_1 c_2 c_3 d_0 d_1 d_2 d_3
0   3 4 5 6 88 77 66 55 ts new thing here 9.1 9.2 9.0 8.4
```

from shape (4,4) to (1, 16)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update let's use the `walrus operator` new in Python 3.8 to create a one-liner:

```
(df_new := df.unstack().to_frame().T).set_axis(
    [f"{i}_{j}" for i, j in df_new.columns], axis=1
)
```

Output:

```
  a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3 b_0 b_1 b_2 b_3 c_0  c_1    c_2   c_3  d_0  d_1  d_2  d_3
0   3   4   5   6  88  77  66  55  ts  new  thing  here  9.1  9.2  9.0  8.4
```

---

Try this, using `unstack`, `to_frame` and transpose.  Next, flatten the column headers using list comprehension:

```
df_new = df.unstack().to_frame().T 
df_new.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in df_new.columns]
df_new
```

Output:

```
  a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3 b_0 b_1 b_2 b_3 c_0  c_1    c_2   c_3  d_0  d_1  d_2  d_3
0   3   4   5   6  88  77  66  55  ts  new  thing  here  9.1  9.2  9.0  8.4
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.assign(
    header = df.index, 
    index = 0)
.pivot_wider(
    index = 'index', 
    names_from = 'header',
    names_sep = '_')
.drop(columns='index')
)
   a_0  a_1  a_2  a_3  b_0  b_1  b_2  b_3 c_0  c_1    c_2   c_3  d_0  d_1  d_2  d_3
0    3    4    5    6   88   77   66   55  ts  new  thing  here  9.1  9.2  9.0  8.4
```